# Reload of Drools 5 - Causes PermGen

Tags: java, drools

I have a problem with reloading dynamically rules. When I'm removing and then adding same rule to KnowledgeBase I see in yourkit that numer of classes loded by Java is inreasing very fast. It's look like adding one rule causing recreate all rules in permgen)

First I'm removing my rule:

```
existingKb.removeRule(pro.pkg, pro.name);
```

and then I'm adding new verions:

```
KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newReaderResource(new StringReader(rule)), ResourceType.DRL);
existingKb.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
```

I searched in the internet and found possible cause:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.drools/drools-core/5.6.0.Final/org/drools/rule/JavaDialectRuntimeData.java#JavaDialectRuntimeData.wire%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.Object%29

Method wire, which creates new instance of class, is calling for every rule while invoking method:

```
kb.addKnowledgePackages
```

Do you know this problem? How to resolve this? I'm using java 7 and drools 5.6 final.

**Solution**

After few trials I managed to fixed this bug. I changed the way I copy existing KnowledgeBase into new:

```
KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder(existingKb);
KnowledgeBase newKb= KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newReaderResource(new StringReader(rule)), ResourceType.DRL);
kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
copyKnowledgePackagesIfNotExist(existingKb, newKb);
existingKb= newKb;

 private void copyKnowledgePackagesIfNotExist(KnowledgeBase oldKb, KnowledgeBase newKb) {
        for (KnowledgePackage oldKnowledgePackage : oldKb.getKnowledgePackages()) {
            KnowledgePackage newKnowledgePackage = newKb.getKnowledgePackage(oldKnowledgePackage.getName());
            if (newKnowledgePackage == null) {
                Collection<KnowledgePackage> knowledgePackageCollection = new ArrayList<>();
                knowledgePackageCollection.add(oldKnowledgePackage);
                newKb.addKnowledgePackages(knowledgePackageCollection);
            }
        }
    }
```

Drools are still creating new classes in Permgen, but they are garbage collected.

Comment: It seems that this has been fixed in 6.x releases.

Comment: It seems? Upgrading to drools 6 is huge change. Is there any workaround to add rules dynamically and not increasing permgen?

Comment: I've found some entries in the bug DB, written just before 6.0. I don't know whether this issue was ever raised during 5.x.

Comment: Can you provide some links to these bugs?

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=973168

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I don't think this is a bug which I mentioned. But good part is that i found a solution (described in first post).